# Axis2 Data Type generation

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, apache, data-binding

I'm new I need your help, and I hope to be helpful in future.
When I try to create a web service starting from Java class

```
public class AddOperation {
    public int add(int a, int b){
        return a+b;
    }   
}
```

with Tomcat 6 Eclipse Helios Axis2 1.6.0 (eclipse plugin) at the time of generating the client and use it get

[Eclipse Plugin creation Server](http://img11.imageshack.us/img11/9281/wscreation.png)
[Eclipse Plugin creation Client](http://img638.imageshack.us/img638/9520/wscreation2.png)

```
public class TestClient {
    public static void testClientOperation() throws RemoteException{    
        AddOperationStub aos = new AddOperationStub();
        Add add = new Add();
        add.setA(2);
        add.setB(3);
        AddResponse addResponse = aos.add(add);
        int result = addResponse.get_return();
        System.out.println("Result is: "+result);
    }
}
```

Instead, expect to have

```
public class TestClient {
    public static void testClientOperation() throws RemoteException{    
        AddOperationStub aos = new AddOperationStub();
        int result = aos.add(2, 3);
        System.out.println("Result is: "+result);
    }
}
```

where I'm wrong, because it creates the type Add?

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 1):

By default Axis2 use doc/lit/wrapped style but what you have expected here is doc/lit/bare style, you need to add following property to services.xml file to generate bare service.

```
<parameter name="doclitBare" locked="false"> true</parameter>
```

If you have further issue write to user list http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/mail-lists.html